# I have set current time format of device in 24 hour , now i need to to calculate time of 12 hour format with "am", "pm" from 24 hour format

Tags: swift

```
func toCheckTimeFormatFromDevice(){
    if Date.is24HoursFormat_1 == true{
        print("phone is set to 24 hours")
        let date = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") //Set timezone that you want
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" //Specify your format that you want
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        print(strDate)
    }else{
        print("phone is set to 12 hours")
    }
}
```

I have set current time format of device in 24 hour , now i want to convert time in 12 hour format with "am", "pm".

Comment: And what is your problem with the given code?

Comment: Adding to @NicoHaase: `is24HoursFormat_1` does not appear to be a standard property of `Date` – you should explain that along with your problem; edit your question rather than answer in comments. After that someone will undoubtedly help you. (BTW `== true` is redundant)

Comment: first i choose date and time format in 24 hour format in device, now i go to app where calculate current time that are getting in 24 hour format but i need time in 12 hour format with AM,PM.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method. It works for me

```
func convertDate12HourFormat(dateStr: String) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
    let dateFromStr = formatter.date(from: dateStr)
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"

    let strFromDate = formatter.string(from: dateFromStr!)
    return strFromDate
}
```